# Grafting crabapple Malus floribunda on M26 rootstock?

Tags: apples, grafting, crabapples

I have an one year old [M26 rootstock](https://apples.extension.org/apple-rootstock-info-m-26/) in my yard, and there is a gorgeous [Malus floribunda](http://www.missouribotanicalgarden.org/PlantFinder/PlantFinderDetails.aspx?taxonid=286525) in front of a building where I work.

M26 is one of the commonest rootstocks for apples (Malus domesticas). Malus floribunda belongs to crabapples though.

Is there any chance grafting floribunda on M26 would work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no obvious reason why it wouldn't work. Many UK nurseries sell crab apples grafted onto apple rootstocks

One possible issue with M26 is that it doesn't produce a very strong root system, and therefore it may need a permanent stake for wind protection, depending on how vigorously the crab apple wants to grow.

If you want to try it, now is the right time of year to do it.

Comment: Thanks for encouragement. I am still hesitating, I never grafted before. Perhaps I will just practice on some unimportant plants this year.